# thumbnail with title - reveal more info on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an element called `web-item` and it contains an image thumbnail, a title and a small paragraph of text.

I made it so the title is at the bottom of the image and the paragraph is hidden, and when you hover over the item the title goes up revealing the text and the image becomes darker and grayscale.

It actually looks pretty good, but I have two major problems:

- First, you'll see in the demo that titles that are too long mess this up and don't show completely until you hover.
- In addition, I noticed that different fonts require different values for the initial `translate()` of the `h3` and the paragraph. There has got to be a better way to do this than to mess around with values until it looks good.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="web-item">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/253/150" alt="" class="item-thumb">
        <h3>Title</h3>                  
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.web-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 253px;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.web-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.web-item a:hover img {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
}
.web-item a:hover p {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.web-item a:hover h3 {
  transform: translateY(0);
  background: none;
}
.web-item img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.web-item h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
  transform: translateY(200%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.web-item p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateY(110%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[You can take a look at a working demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mbevnsrw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I have change your html as well as css structure to make cross browser compatible  please check

```css
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
.web-item {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 253px;
 margin: 1em 0;
}
.web-item a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.web-item li:hover img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(0.5);
}
.web-item li div.text{
 transform: translateY(67%);
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
.web-item li:hover div.text {
 transform: translateY(0);
}
.web-item li:hover h3 {
 background: none;
}
.web-item img {
 width: 100%;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.web-item h3 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 500;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 color: #fff;
 background: linear-gradient(transparent, #000);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:15px 15px 10px;
}
.web-item p {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #fff;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 padding:0 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="web-item">
    <li>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/253/150" alt="" class="item-thumb">
        <div class="text">
        <h3>Title</h3>                  
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

also you can check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxjtmv2o/) here

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see the title (when short) is not all the way to the bottom of the image and you can actually see some of the text. I want the title to be at the absolute bottom of the image and the text to be invisible until hover.

Comment: I have just make a demo, you can adjust position as per your requirement. For you information you can change the "transform: translateY(67%)" to 70%. It will solve your issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Html**

```
<div class="web-item">  <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/253/150" alt="" class="item-thumb">
        <div class="web-content">    
        <h3>Works Fine</h3>                         
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
            </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="web-item">  <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/253/150" alt="" class="item-thumb">
            <div class="web-content">    
        <h3>Too Long. Things Are Getting Bad.</h3>                      
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
            </div>    
    </a>
</div>
<div class="web-item different-font">   <a href="#">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/253/150" alt="" class="item-thumb">
            <div class="web-content">    
        <h3>Different font</h3>                         
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
                </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.web-item{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 253px;
    height:150px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin:10px 0;
}

.web-item a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
.web-item a:hover .web-content{    
    top:5px;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.web-item h3{    
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;

}
.web-content{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-95px;
    transition: all 1s;
    padding:5px;
}
.web-content p{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8p25bekt/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not remotely close to what I wanted. There is no animation, without hover the title is not even showing up, and there is no grayscale.

Comment: @gofilord, this is not a freelancing site, people are helping you, i just made a sample for you, you've to alter as per your need..